# Library for gradient boosting tree

Tags: python, c, machine-learning

Do you know of a good library for gradient boosting tree machine learning?

preferably:

- with good algorithms such as AdaBoost, TreeBoost, AnyBoost, LogitBoost, etc
- with configurable weak classifiers
- capable of both classification and prediction (regression)
- with all kinds of allowed signals: numbers, categories or free text
- C/C++ or Python
- opensource

So far I have found http://www.multiboost.org/home which looks good. But I wonder if there are other libraries?

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for a python version, the latest release of [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) features gradient boosted regression trees for classification and regression ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-boosting)).

It is similar to R's gbm package - gbm is faster for (least-squares) regression wheres scikit-learn's implementation is faster at test-time and when your number of features > 1000.

Answer (score 3):

These don't neccessarily meet all your preferences, but there's also:

- [Treenet](http://www.salford-systems.com/products/treenet/overview.html) a commercialization and extension of Jerome Friedman's original implementation.  Not open source but we've found it to work pretty well
- [R gbm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm) for gradient boosted trees specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend xgboost (which did not exist by the time the question was asked), which is an open source R/python package.

It is currently among the fastest gradient boosting tree methods that exists, allows for regression/classification, supports sparse matrices...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer running [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (which is java) using python subprocess module. However my colleagues frequently use:

- [orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) — recommended to me as the best Machine Learning toolkit for Python.
- [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) — which is C++, but has python bindings. This library was originally developed for Computer Vision but has many ML algorithms implemented (including [boosting](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/boosting.html)).

Comment: Weka looks good, thanks. Orange doesn't seem to support gradient boosting trees (afaik supports only one tree). OpenCV supports boosting trees but seems quite specialized toward computer vision (we need it more for text analysis so I'm not sure if it's usable). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, my previous answer about xgboost seems oudated given the latest developments of [LightGBM](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/) implementing various tree based learning algorithms :

- [GBDT](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradient-boosting-decision-tree.pdf), Gradient boosting decision tree
- [DART](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01866.pdf), or Dropouts meet Multiple Additive Regression Trees
- GOSS, or Gradient-based One-Side Sampling
- Random Forest

It also has a [Python API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html).